# Most efficient way to determine if a list is empty

Tags: c#, optimization

I have a function which will be called thousands of times per day, and I want to optimize this function so it will be as fast and efficient as possible.

In this function, a list will be checked and based on the result of this check, different actions will happen. My question is what is the most efficient way of determining how many elements are in this list.

Obviously, you can just check like this:

```
List<Objects> data = GetData();
if (data.Count == 0)
{
    //Do something
}
else if (data.Count < 5)
{
    //Do something with a small list
}
else
{
    //Do something with a larger list
}
```

Is this already the fastest/most efficient way of doing this?
I came up with an alternative, but I would like some suggestions

```
List<Objects> data = GetData();
int amountOfObjects = data.Count();
if (amountOfObjects == 0)
{
    //Do something
}
else if (amountOfObjects < 5)
{
    //Do something with a small list
}
else
{
    //Do something with a larger list
}
```

Comment: `int amountOfObjects = data.Count();` is certainly not more efficient than `int amountOfObjects = data.Count;`

Comment: There's no way anything will be faster than using `List<T>.Count`

Comment: Those 2 are doing exactly the same thing, the second one really isn't faster in any way.

Comment: if you want get better performance write your program or part of it in `c++`

Comment: I would personally question why you are attempting to micro-optimise in this way, if you are wasting a lot of time because of what this method is doing I'd first question your applications architecture and see if you can optimise at a higher level.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary But the overhead of calling P/Invoke is quite high, and likely to make the end result slower overall.

Comment: So your code is working and you just want to make it faster... Maybe you would like to post it in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Gabriel sorry I wasn't aware there was something like that, I'll use that next time!

Comment: A thousand times per day? I never considered performance of `Count` even if it was called millions of times. Read about YAGNI. Don't do performance optimizazion before you know where the performance impact actually is.

Comment: @ThomasWeller well thank you for your input, I just try to keep my methods as efficient as possible!

Comment: Its good to keep things as efficient as possible, but not so good to obsess about making things more efficient than necessary. Consider if this piece of code is causing any real timing problems now or likely to in the future. Best case saving is likely to be calculated in microseconds per iteration, so calling thousands of times - time saving will be in milliseconds - is there any part of your application that will fail without that time saving or be noticeably better performing. If not don't waste the time needed to make unnecessary improvements - get on with more important things.

Comment: Thank you paul, I'll definitely keep that in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the property `Count` as it is a pre-calculated value and will not require recalculating the value when you use it, whereas the method `Count()` will try to be a smart ass and try to work out if it needs to recount or not, but that working out alone is still more effort than just using `Count`.

So just use what you have initially done.

Comment: Alright thank you! All I wanted to know if there was a faster option to counting a list

Comment: @Bas: As a comment suggests, [codereview.se] is probably worth looking at for performance concerns

Comment: Actually, [it won't](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b). It's optimised to check if the enumerable implements `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection` (which `List<T>` does) and it returns the result from the `Count` property. That said, you should probably just call it directly.

Comment: Actually, the implementation of `Enumerable.Count` will try to cast to ` ICollection<TSource>` first and use the `.Count` property if that succeeds - but of course that itself has a lot of overhead compared to just using the property without casting.

Comment: @CharlesMager: Thanks for that link, I didn't know that resource existed! Very useful to know!

Comment: I'm not expert. but doesn't jitter optimize these things? I think ive heard that jitter can do some magic but I don't know if I'm right or not

Answer (score 1):

For `List<T>`, the `Count` property really just returns a field because the implementation is an array list that needs to know very precisely how many elements are in this collection. Therefore, you won't gain any performance by trying to cache this value or anything alike. This is just no problem.

This situation may be different when you use other collection implementations. For example, a `LinkedList` conceptually has no clue of how many elements are in it, but has to count them, which is an expensive operation.

**Edit:** Your alternative using `Count()` is actually a very bad thing. Since `List<T>` is sealed, the compiler will create a static method call for accessing the `Count` property meanwhile `Count()` results in a cast and a virtual method call over an interface. That makes up much more cost and the JIT-compiler can do less magic such as inlining.